# Is it possible to make the join node to count the number of messages arriving on it on Node-RED?

Tags: node-red

I've created the following flow on Node-RED:

[image]

It's the smallest possible example that I could think of... It's working fine. However, I'd like to make the join node automatically detect the number of lines connected to it. In this example, I had six lines connected so I had to manually specify 6 lines inside the join node as the following:

[image]

Is there any workaround to make a node detect the number of lines connected to it? I'm not sure if the join node can do it, but if not, can the function node receive this parameter somehow? Just so I could implement my own version of the join node? Is it possible to do on Node-RED?

Answer (score 0):

No, the nodes have no way to determine what is connected to them. This is very intentional.

The Join node can be informed about how many input msg's to expect using the `parts` object attached to the msg object. It's format is described in the sidebar doc for both the join and split nodes.

> **parts**
>
> This property contains information about how the message was split
> from the original message. If passed to the join node, the sequence
> can be reassembled into a single message. The property has the
> following properties:
>
> - *id* - an identifier for the group of messages
>   index - the position within the group
>   count - if known, the total number of messages in the group. See 'streaming mode' below.
> - *type* - the type of message - string/array/object/buffer
> - *ch* - for a string or buffer, the data used to the split the message as either the string or an array of bytes
> - *key* - for an object, the key of the property this message was created from. The node can be configured to also copy this value to
>   another message properties, such as msg.topic.
> - *len* - the length of each message when split using a fixed length value

Comment: I see... I think the workaround for me is setting a small time like 10ms to join the messages then. I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but using the `parts` object means that the message was first split with the `split` node, is that right? In my case the messages that I'm joining were never split... Would that be a problem or I can "fake" that my messages were split using the split node by setting the right `parts` object?

Comment: It doesn't have to come from the split node, just needs to be consistent with that format.